# How to create model for search for multi table in yii2

Tags: php, yii2, searchqueryset

I want to search in a multi table in yii2. How to do this action?

```
<?php

namespace app\models;

use Yii;
use yii\db\Query;
use app\models\Article;
use app\models\Certificates;
use app\models\News;
use app\models\Pages;
use app\models\Projects;
use app\models\NewsSearch;
```

i want search in multi table. that table have not any relation with Together

i want write query in yii2 like this :

```
select *   from news , article , projects where (any column for this tables ) like %search%
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using  relation   adding the activeRelation the your main model and then use the relation in a proper search function
 eg ( just a brief suggestion) :

```
/* ActiveRelation */
public function getMyExtModelRelation()
{
   return $this->hasOne(MyExtModel::className(), ['id' => 'ext_id']);
}
```

and in main modelSearch

```
/* search function  */ 

 .....
 ....
// filter by MyExtModel attribute
 $query->joinWith(['myExModelRelation' => function ($q) {
     $q->where('tbl_my_ext_model.my_attribute LIKE "%' . $this->my_attribute . '%"');
}]);
```

Here you can find a good tutorial for common related and calculated  search filter and sort http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/621/filter-sort-by-calculated-related-fields-in-gridview-yii-2-0/

I don't understand what you are trynd to do and the result of your query could be huge and of little use but anyway if you 
want a genaric query you can use

```
use yii\db\Query;
.....
$connection = \Yii::$app->db;

$any_column  = "your_any_column";
$any_search  = " concat('%', '". $your_search ."', '%'); "
$sql ="select *   from news, article , projects  where " . $any_column  . $any_search ;

$yourModels  = $connection->createCommand($sql);->queryAll();
```

could be you must assign alias to the column that you use in select for retrive this column from models or use the complete name (tablename.columnname)

Comment: i want search in multi table.
that table have not any relation with Together
i updated this post.

Comment: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'concat('%', yes, '%')' at line 1
The SQL being executed was: select * from news, article where news.fTitle concat('%', yes, '%');  !!!!!